# Fire ajax by on click only once with equal classes

Tags: jquery, ajax, click

i am running an ajax script via on click with classes, that occure many times.
The script is fired many times. With

event.stopPropagation();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();

i nearly solved the problem, but parts of the script (open a layer) does not work with the solution. here is the script

```
// over 30 layers with .openFieldsButton
$(document).on("click", '.openFieldsButton', function(event) {

  var id = $(this).attr('fields_id');

  var relid = $(this).attr('relid_to_select');

  var this_ = this;

  var forms_token = $(this).attr('forms_token');

  $(this).removeClass('openFieldsButton');

  $(this).parent().find('.loadingGif').show();

  $(this).parent().find('.openIconToggleBox').hide();

  $(this).parent().find('.openIconToggleBox').removeClass('glyphicon-menu-down').addClass('glyphicon-menu-up');



  $.ajax({
    url: '?isloaded=1&open_id=' + id + '&open_relid=' + relid + forms_token + '',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: {'load_content' : id, 'open_relid': relid, 'isloaded': '1'},
      success: function(response) {

        $(this_).parent().find('.loadingGif').hide();

      $(this_).parent().find('.openIconToggleBox').show(); //with stop propagation is doesn't open

      $('#fields_' + id + '').html(response.toggleBoxFields);

          event.stopPropagation();
          event.stopImmediatePropagation();

      }
  });



  });
```

Comment: "but parts of the script (open a layer) does not work with the solution" I have no clue what that means

Comment: Note that the event has long completed by the time the ajax success runs so trying to preventDefault or propagation inside success is too late to be of any use. I doubt this is really related to your specific problem though which is very unclear

Comment: i already used preventDefault, but with this tag it is still fired many times

Comment: What does "fired many times" actually mean? Are you saying a single click makes multiple ajax requests? You really have not done a good job of explaining the problem in detail

Comment: To open the layer bootstrap does the job by adding a class show, it is therfore not working when stopPropagation is used. Now I try to add a class show in the success part.

Comment: I solved it by adding a class show: $(this_).closest('.MyWordsToggleBox').find('.MyWordsShow').addClass('show');